# Delete set of lines in multiple .dat files in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I searched for similar topics but could not find the same. I want to delete lines 1 to 85 in multiple dat files. 
Can this be done with FindReplace in Notepad++?

Comment: I think this question is more suited in this site: https://superuser.com

Comment: I think this is a job for a script, do you know some?

Comment: Not (yet). Looking into this for the past hour or so. Maybe with a help of a macro in excell and then run it through multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

For each of your files do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `\A([^\r\n]*\R){85}`
- **Replace With:** nothing
- check **regular expression**
- click Replace or Replace All

If that works well (and you have created a backup): you can do the same with the *Find in Files* tab using the *Replace in Files* button. If you can give a pattern for your multiple files that should do the trick nicely.

**Here is how it works**

- `\A` matches at the start of a file
- `([^\r\n]*\R)` matches a whole line up to the lineend (should works with Windows and Unix lineendings dur to `\R`)
- `{85}` finally matches exactly 85 repetitions of the previous expression, thus the first 85 lines are replace with nothing, i.e. deleted

Comment: Hi Lars, thank you so much for your effort. It works like a charm. You saved me hours of work! Cheers!

Comment: Except that it has problems handling multiple files. When I hit Find in Files it seems that the script deletes 85 files continuously throughout the file, until less than 85 files remain. This is then all that is left of the initial files. Is there something one could do to stop the multiple deletions on a single file?